# Error : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns the below error.

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting expression to data type int. Warning: Null value is
>   eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

**Sql**

```
SELECT
  Brands.BrandName AS [Brand],
  Outlets.OutletName AS [Outlet],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(ms, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) / 60000 AS [Receive],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(ms, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate)) / 60000 AS [Ready],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(ms, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate)) / 60000 AS [Dispatch],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(ms, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate, ClosedOrders.ClosingDate)) / 60000 AS [Close]
FROM dbo.Orders
INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets
  ON dbo.Orders.OutletID = dbo.Outlets.OutletID
INNER JOIN dbo.Brands
  ON dbo.Brands.BrandID = dbo.Outlets.BrandID
INNER JOIN dbo.ReceivedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReceivedOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ReadyOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ReadyOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.DispatchedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.DispatchedOrders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ClosedOrders
  ON dbo.Orders.OrderID = dbo.ClosedOrders.OrderID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '2017-04-1' AND '2017-05-10'
AND ((dbo.Brands.BrandName IS NULL
OR dbo.Brands.BrandName LIKE '%' + '' + '%')
AND (dbo.Outlets.OutletName IS NULL
OR dbo.Outlets.OutletName LIKE '%' + '' + '%'))
GROUP BY Brands.BrandName,
         dbo.Outlets.OutletName
ORDER BY dbo.Outlets.OutletName, Brands.BrandName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of milliseconds between your dates - which you then divide - meaning that SQL needs to do a conversion - which apparently, with the dates you have overflows the integer type it is trying to convert o.

So, you are getting the difference between your dates as milliseconds, then dividing by 60,000 to get minutes. Why not get those in minutes to begin with? Chances of such an overflow are much lower this way.

Instead of:

```
AVG(DATEDIFF(ms, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) / 60000 AS [Receive]
```

Do:

```
AVG(DATEDIFF(mi, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)) AS [Receive]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for milliseconds max is around difference of 25 days: So you can change to seconds and divide accordingly

```
  AVG(DATEDIFF(s, Orders.OrderDate, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate)/60.0) AS [Receive],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(s, ReceivedOrders.ReceivingDate, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate)/60.0)  AS [Ready],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(s, ReadyOrders.ReadyDate, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate)/60.0)  AS [Dispatch],
  AVG(DATEDIFF(s, DispatchedOrders.DispatchedDate, ClosedOrders.ClosingDate)/60.0) AS [Close]
```

MSDN:
If the return value is out of range for int (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647), an error is returned. For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql